# visualvm intellij "Failed to create JMX connection to target application" profiling not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visualvm

I am trying to use visualVM for profiling a simple java application that I am debugging with Intellij. I start the application to debug, open visualVM, and I can see my application in the list. I can open it; however, I am unable to use sampling or profiling for my application. Other applications, such as Intellij, can be profiled just fine. When I check the visualVM logs I see:

INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl]: connect(2749)
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded

more information:
Operating System = Mac OS X version 10.9.1 running on x86_64
Java; VM; Vendor = 1.7.0_51; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03; Oracle Corporation
Intellij IDEA = 13.0.2

if anyone has this working, please let me know how you got it. I would like to use the Intellij VisualVMLauncher as well if I can get it going.

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well, and none of the answers thus far have resolved it for me.

Comment: Here's my logfile from VisualVM: http://www.pastey.org/view/c579846c. @nashspence, could you grab your logfile from VisualVM->About->Logfile?

Answer (score 22):

Maybe [this helps](http://statkwon.blogspot.dk/2013/06/java-profiling-with-visualvm-on-mac.html):

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -jar xxx.jar
```

Answer (score 10):

This looks the [JDK bug #8023786](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023786). Until this is fixed in JDK 7u60, you can run the profiled application with -XX:+StartAttachListener. Some details about this bug are also in [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-October/006093.html) email thread.

Comment: Hey I'll try that when I get a chance. Been traveling. Thanks for the response.

Comment: im still having trouble getting this to work even starting my application using that flag. I find visualvm just starts to hang whenever I attempt to open the application for profiling. i intend to keep looking into the issue, but if you have any other recommendations they would be welcome

Comment: Maybe it didn't help the OP, but it helped me. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me, but [Thomas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957888/816458) below did.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue earlier when running a standalone visualvm. Instead, try running the visualvm bundled with the same jdk used to run the application (in my case  c:\jdk1.7.0\bin\jvisualvm.exe) and it may not need jmx in the first place.

Comment: this ended up solving this for you? As far as I can tell, I am using the jvisualvm from the same jdk that I am running the application on.

Comment: I also had this problem and in my case it was caused by the fact, that the app was running with a 32-bit JDK, but I used a 64-bit VisualVM.

Comment: Solved the problem for me in two different cases.

Answer (score 0):

If it may help anyone, a solution I found was to launch the application in IntelliJ via the [VisualVM launcher plugin for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7115-visualvm-launcher) . It worked for me with a web application on Glassfish.

Comment: This should be the best solution but the VisualVM Launcher buttons are never enabled for me.