# VisualVM profiling on OS X Mavericks and JDK 1.7

Tags: java, macos

I can't get VisualVM to profile local applications on OSX (although this works just fine on my Windows machine).

I am using:

- OSX: 10.9.4
- JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04, mixed mode)
- Java: version 1.7.0_67, vendor Oracle Corporation

I find that I have to run jvisualvm (and my target application) with "sudo" otherwise the terminal window shows the following error (with a longer error appearing in the VisualVM log file):

> attach: task_for_pid(6136) failed (5)

Running with sudo isn't ideal, but I can live with it.

However even when I run with sudo, the CPU graph on the Monitor tab shows:

> Not supported for this JVM

The other graphs on the Monitor tab seem to be populated correctly, but the Summary on the Sampler tab shows:

> **CPU sampling:** 
>   Not available. Failed to create JMX connection to target
>   application. Use 'Add JMX Connection' action to attach to the
>   application.
>
> **Memory sampling:** 
>   Not available. Cannot connect to target application.
>   Make sure the application is running on a supported JDK 6 or JDK 7.

And the VisualVM log shows:

> WARNING [com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl]: The JMX management agent cannot be 
>   enabled in this application (pid 5666)

I have tried using "XX:+StartAttachListener" as per [visualvm intellij "Failed to create JMX connection to target application" profiling not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084052/visualvm-intellij-failed-to-create-jmx-connection-to-target-application-profil)

I have also checked that my hostname resolves to an address other than 127.0.0.1 as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/faq.html#linux1

Neither of these helped :(

Does anyone know how to get VisualVM profiling working on OSX Mavericks?

If so is it possible to get it to work without using sudo?

Comment: Try upgrading your JVM. This message *Not supported for this JVM* seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Thanks but 1.7.0_67 is currently the latest JDK 7.

Comment: I'm not using Mavericks, but [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html) **is** available for Mac.

Comment: That's true. I'm actually working in Scala, not in Java; and our target environment is Java 7. Still it's worth a shot to see if the VisualVM profiler works out of the box I suppose. Thanks.